# Why is jQuery .val() returning nothing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the value of an input. Here is what my form looks like:

[image]

This is the HTML for it:

```html
<label for="userName"></label>
<input type="text" class="form-input plain-text" id="userName" placeholder="Username">
```

Here is the jQuery to get its value and log it:

```js
$("#loginSubmit").click(function() {
    var userName = $("#userName").val();
    console.log(userName);
});
```

But when I type in some text and hit the login button that has the id `#userName`, the console returns this:

[image]

Why does this not output `dwedwed` in the console?

Thanks

---

Solution found in comments

Debugging: I found I have more than one input with the same ID

Comment: [I can't reproduce it](https://jsfiddle.net/ue3dxpst/). Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Maybe you have multiple elements with `id="userName"`. IDs need to be unique.

Comment: maybe your submit button has a different ID?

Comment: Can you post the whole html,  I can not see your sumbit buttion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Immediate reasons I can see are:

- you are attaching an event before the DOM is even loaded or before the element is available in the DOM (if you're loading JS in the head instead of bottom of body for example)
- multiple element's with the same ID
- you have a stopPropagation on button elements (or this particular identifier) which is blocking the callback

Other than the above, it's hard to determine what is going on without more code/information.

If its a matter of *when* you are attaching the listener, try adding `$(document).ready()` around your event listener.

Comment: The error was that I had multiple inputs with the same ID thank you